# File uploading even after Exception (FileNotFoundException (Access is Denied))

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, upload, filenotfoundexception

I have created a servlet that uploads a file, selected by user from a form.

HTML Form snippet is:

```
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="UploadFile">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputModuleName">Module Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputModuleName" placeholder="Module Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="fileName">
    <p class="help-block">Only .docx & .pdf files</p>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputComment">Comments</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Write here..."></textarea>
</div>
<button name="uploadButton" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
```

Note: Only file type input is relevant here as it is a test page. No other inputs fields are processed as per now.

and Servlet code is :

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.sql.*;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;

    @MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*2, maxFileSize=1024*1024*5)
    public class UploadFile extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String appPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    String saveDir = getServletContext().getInitParameter("uploaddir");
    String savePath = appPath + saveDir;

    File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);

    try{
        for(Part part : request.getParts()){
            String fileName = extractFileName(part);
            part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
        }
        out.println("File uploaded!!!");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    out.println("Error: Can't Upload");
    }
}

private String extractFileName(Part part) {
    String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");
    for (String s : items) {
        if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length()-1);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
}
```

When I submit the form it always throws an Exception and I get the following output in the console but file gets uploaded to the folder:

```
java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\tomcat\webapps\proto1\filesupload (Access is denied)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.write(ApplicationPart.java:121)
    at UploadFile.doPost(UploadFile.java:30)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2466)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2455)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\tomcat\webapps\proto1\filesupload (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.write(ApplicationPart.java:119)
    ... 24 more
```

How to resolve this issue ?

Some points to consider:

- I am using Windows 8.1 OS with Apache Tomcat 7 server.
- `saveFileDir.canRead()` and `saveFileDir.canWrite()` both return `true`.
- edited permission from security settings of folder to 'full modify'.

Comment: Can you verify after right clicking that folder that you gave the permissions to the correct user only .

Comment: Yes, I gave permissions to current user only at first but when it didn't work I applied same permissions for all users.

Comment: When you paste in the windows explorer 
C:\tomcat\webapps\proto1\filesupload, do you see the file ? I mean does this path actually exist ?

Comment: Yes, the folder exists there and the uploaded file can also be opened properly i.e. it is not corrupted in any way.

Comment: Can you try calling canRead() method just to see if you have permission..

Comment: That I mentioned in the question already. It is returning true for both canRead() and canWrite(). Also, I had used setWritable(true) and setReadable(true), but it didn't helped.

Comment: See my answer...Try it

Answer (score 0):

Try using `File.separator` instead of placing slash in your path...
This ensures using an OS dependent path separator.

Its redundant to say this but still try with double backward slashes.. "\\" .

Heres a link from where I read.

[Read here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html)

Comment: You mean like:String appPath = request.getServletContext();
    String saveDir = getServletContext().getInitParameter("uploaddir");
    String savePath = appPath +File.separator+ saveDir;

Comment: Nope. It didn't help.

Comment: Can you print the complete path and paste here. ? I mean the savePath variable

Comment: savePath : C:\tomcat\webapps\proto1\filesupload

Comment: Its redundant to say this but still try with forward slash... "/"

Comment: Sorry. I didn't got what you want me to try. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Tried using the following savePath value (explicitly assigned it) as C:\\tomcat\\webapps\\proto1\\filesupload ,but the problem still persists.

Comment: get a solution to this?